# Catch Firestore error in valueChanges subscription and retry in case of failure

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore to store data for my Angular app. I created a service and read data e.g. like this:

```
retrieveCollectionColors(name) {
  this.db.collectionGroup('collection-colors', ref => ref.where('product', '==', name))
    .valueChanges().subscribe( (val: []) => {
    this.collectionColors.next(val);
  });
}
```

**How can I catch errors and if one occurs, how can I retry the query?**

Comment: @PeterHaddad 's is correct - however, just based on how you've worded the question, watch out that you don't just retry the same query as soon as you get an error and end up in a loop. If something is actively incorrect and it wasn't just a connection issue, re-running the same query will not suddenly make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `subscribe` method contains a second argument incase of error:

> `Rx.Observable.prototype.subscribe([observer] | [onNext], [onError], [onCompleted])`
>
> - [observer] (Observer): The object that is to receive notifications.
> - [onNext] (Function): Function to invoke for each element in the observable sequence.
> - [onError] (Function): Function to invoke upon exceptional termination of the observable sequence.
> - [onCompleted] (Function): Function to invoke upon graceful termination of the observable sequence.

Therefore do the following:

```
.valueChanges().subscribe( (val: []) => {
    this.collectionColors.next(val);
  },error => {
  console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to catch the error and re-run you code:

```
  this.db.collectionGroup('collection-colors', ref => ref.where('product', '==', name))
    .valueChanges().subscribe( (val: []) => {
    this.collectionColors.next(val);
  }, error => {
// Do your stuff here
console.log(error);
});
```